# downsampling time series equally spaced points for line plots

Tags: mysql, sql, fastapi

I have a large database with around 75K points. This database represents a time series associated with countries with the following format:

```
|country | value | date |
```

I am using a fastapi API to serve this data on my front. Since the chart library I use will not use more than 300 points, I'd like to downsample the time series so that I have 300 points equally spaced, including first point and last point for each country.

As for now, I have come up with this SQL solution:

```
WITH
    E AS (
        SELECT *,
        PERCENT_RANK() OVER w as rw
        FROM my_table
        WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY date)
    )
SELECT *, FLOOR(300*rw) as sel FROM E GROUP BY E.country, sel;
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this / more optimized way?

I'm already using indexes, and I'm unsure if partitions on the SQL database has any impact

## Example

If I downsample to 5 points per country, I would like to go from this:

```
+---------+--------+------------+
| country | value  | date       |
+---------+--------+------------+
| ar      |   1.4  | 2010-02-03 |
| ar      |   1.4  | 2010-02-04 |
| ar      |   1.3  | 2010-02-05 |
| ar      |   1.4  | 2010-02-06 |
| ar      |   1.2  | 2010-02-07 |
| ar      |   1.4  | 2010-02-08 |
| ar      |   1.5  | 2010-02-09 |
| ar      |   1.7  | 2010-02-10 |
| ar      |   1.4  | 2010-02-11 |
| ar      |   1.6  | 2010-02-12 |
| ar      |   1.4  | 2010-02-13 |
| ar      |   1.5  | 2010-02-14 |
| ar      |   1.3  | 2010-02-15 |
| ar      |   1.2  | 2010-02-16 |
| fr      |   1.3  | 2010-02-03 |
| fr      |   1.3  | 2010-02-04 |
| fr      |   1.4  | 2010-02-05 |
| fr      |   1.6  | 2010-02-06 |
| fr      |   1.9  | 2010-02-07 |
| fr      |   1.3  | 2010-02-08 |
| fr      |   1.3  | 2010-02-09 |
| fr      |   1.2  | 2010-02-10 |
| fr      |   1.3  | 2010-02-11 |
| fr      |   1.5  | 2010-02-12 |
| fr      |   1.3  | 2010-02-13 |
| fr      |   1.3  | 2010-02-14 |
| fr      |   1.5  | 2010-02-15 |
| fr      |   1.3  | 2010-02-16 |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

To this:

```
+---------+--------+------------+
| country | value  | date       |
+---------+--------+------------+
| ar      |   1.4  | 2010-02-03 |
| ar      |   1.4  | 2010-02-06 |
| ar      |   1.5  | 2010-02-09 |
| ar      |   1.4  | 2010-02-13 |
| ar      |   1.2  | 2010-02-16 |
| fr      |   1.3  | 2010-02-03 |
| fr      |   1.6  | 2010-02-06 |
| fr      |   1.3  | 2010-02-09 |
| fr      |   1.3  | 2010-02-13 |
| fr      |   1.3  | 2010-02-16 |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

## Edit 2

With @Rick James answer, I've come up with this:

```
SELECT country, FLOOR(300*(TO_DAYS(date) - x.da) /(x.dd - x.da)) as g, date, value
    FROM table
    JOIN ( SELECT TO_DAYS(MIN(date)) AS da, TO_DAYS(MAX(date)) as dd, country as cc
              FROM table GROUP BY country
         ) AS x
         ON table.country = x.cc
    GROUP BY country, g;
```

I can tell this is faster, but as I am no expert, I can't tell if it is the best I can get / if it is not an absurd way of doing this

Comment: Give concrete examples. Sample representative data, and the expected results *(for example, 10 actual data points sampled down to 3, and the same data points sampled down to 5)*, then we can SEE the logic you're trying to achieve; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: I have updated with an example! Please tell me if it is sufficient enough!

Comment: You say your example down samples to 4 data points, but you shown 5 rows per country.

Comment: Yes sorry, I've edited the example to match what I said

Comment: If looking at the gaps between each row (so the number of rows skipped / removed) they are 2,2,3,2. Would gaps of 3,2,2,2 be acceptable? Or any other distribution? Or is the specific distribution required?

Comment: Any distribution among the following are acceptable:
`3,2,2,2`
`2,3,2,2`
`2,2,3,2`
`2,2,2,3`

Comment: The only requirement would be to keep the first and last value in the downsampling

Answer (score 0):

I would develop a formula that maps the date a number such that MIN(date) maps to 0.5 and MAX(date) maps to 299.5.

```
SELECT country, ROUND(...that formula...), AVG(value)
    FROM t
    GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Note that `AVG` will effectively smooth out the curve rather than picking a particular entry (which might be especially high or low.).

Putting the pieces together:

```
 SELECT country,
       ROUND((TO_DAYS(date) - x.da) / x.span),
       AVG(value)
    FROM my_table
    JOIN ( SELECT TO_DAYS(MIN(date)) AS da,
                  ROUND((TO_DAYS(MAX(date)) -
                         TO_DAYS(MIN(date))) / 6) AS span
              FROM my_table
         ) AS x
    GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Comment: The op doesn't show an averaging, but rather an actual down sampling.

Comment: Behaves badly in a bunch of scenarios: https://dbfiddle.uk/5NQeZDZE

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/7uMUSn3D

Comment: It's closer now.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY country
          ORDER BY date     -- choose a different column name!
    ) - 1
      AS row_id,
    COUNT(*) OVER (
      PARTITION BY country
    ) - 1
      AS step
  FROM
    my_table
)
SELECT
  sorted.*
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
  mod( row_id             * 4, step)
  <
  mod((row_id + step - 1) * 4, step)
ORDER BY
  country, row_id
```

The hard-coded `* 4` should be `* (sample_size - 1)`

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/llmch7nm

***EDIT:***

The above behaves badly when the starting data set size is smaller than the target sample size.

This demo has two different fudges to work around that : https://dbfiddle.uk/J0Nb_CNb